# When does A not extends A in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-level-computation

For reasons not relevant to the question (but which include fun and profit in type-level programming), one of my types eventually boils down to the following minimal example:

```js
type IsTrue<A extends true> = A
type Refl<M> = M extends M ? true : false
type Proof<M> = IsTrue<Refl<M>>
```

... which results in a compile error. Now, we *can* discuss how I ended up here, and *it is* related to a (probably) wrong way of encoding Type Equality. But the question remains: When doesn't `M extends M` resolves to `true` for all `M`? What's the counter-example? How would one go to fix this (possibly by constraining `M`)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `type Refl<M> = M extends M ? true : false` which is more minimal and has the same issue?

Comment: No, you're right. Let me change.

Comment: The answer here is going to be that there isn't a counterexample, but that the compiler defers evaluation of such conditional types that depend on as-yet unspecified generic type parameters.  It doesn't analyze the form of such a type to see if the conditional type could be optimized away, because ~99% of the time it can't be, and the ~1% of the time where it could isn't worth the cost of the analysis.  It only knows that `Refl<M>` is constrained to `true | false` and thus `IsTrue<Refl<M>>` is not known to be safe. You can write `Refl<Extract<M, true>>` if you want to work around it.

Comment: I can write up an answer if you want but I'm going to look for some canonical source to back up the explanation first.

Comment: That seems like a useful answer, @jcalz, thx!

Comment: BTW, in the original formulation (`M extends M ? (M extends M ? true : false) : false`), one `Extract` is not enough. Would there be a general way of forcing the "computation" of the types for an arbitrary (though I imagine bounded) depth?

Comment: Ugh, I meant `Extract<Refl<M>, true>`, not `Refl<Extract<M, true>>` 

Comment: Okay, I'm thinking https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46155 is as close to a canonical source for this as possible.  I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), as originally implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#21316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) are not always evaluated *eagerly*.  If they depend on an as-yet-unspecified generic type parameter, like the `M` inside the body of the `Refl<M>` definition, the compiler will generally *defer* evaluation of the conditional type.  Note that the details about exactly when and where the compiler will evaluate a conditional type are not spelled out in any documentation, and they've been evolving over time with new releases of TypeScript, so I can't say anything with absolute certainty here.  But the general situation is as I've described it.

You were expecting the compiler to look at `M extends M ? true : false` and eagerly reduce it to `true` so that your definition would be equivalent to `type Refl<M> = true`, either inside the definition of `Refl<M>` or inside the definition of `Proof<M>`.  Neither of these evaluations happen; they are deferred because in both cases `M` is an unspecified type parameter.  So the compiler cannot be sure that `Refl<M>` will be any narrower than the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `true | false` (also known as [the `boolean` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean)), and thus is not known to satisfy the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `IsTrue<A extends true>`.

So it isn't that `M extends M ? true : false` should ever actually evaluate to `false` (as far as I know it can't), but that the compiler fails to evaluate it at all in order to simplify it to `true`.

I don't see any GitHub issues about this specific circumstance, but there are many such issues which boil down to the compiler's inability to analyze conditional types that depend on an unresolved generic type parameter.  For a relatively recent example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#46795](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46795).

---

Note that the particular form `M extends ... ? ... : ...` where `M` is a plain generic type parameter is known as a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and so any unions in `M` would be broken into individual members before being evaluated.  This doesn't affect whether `Refl<M>` could ever be wider than `true`, but it can affect the output type:

```
type Refl<M> = M extends M ? true : false
type Hmm = Refl<never> // never
type Refl2<M> = [M] extends [M] ? true : false;
type Hmm2 = Refl2<never> // true
```

`Refl<M>` is distributive over unions in `M`, and `never` is considered to be "the empty union" (see [this comment in ms/TS#23182](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672)) and thus the output is also the empty union.  But `Refl2<M>` is not distributive (since `[M]` is not a plain generic type parameter) and so `Refl2<never>` is `true`.  Both `never` and `true` are assignable to `true`, though, so `IsTrue<Refl<M>>` would work out no matter what.  But it's trickier than it might seem to demonstrate that.

---

It is conceivable that a feature could be introduced whereby conditional types of the form `X extends X ? Y : Z` could be eagerly reduced to `Y` in cases where `Y` does not depend on `X` (your case) or where `X` is not a plain generic type parameter (not your case).  But such a feature would have a negative effect on compiler performance, since it would need to check every conditional type for this situation even though the vast majority of conditional types are not like this; features need to pay for themselves, and this one probably wouldn't.  Even worse, there's probably a lot of real-world code that either intentionally or unintentionally depends on the compiler deferring conditional types like this, and such a feature would be a large breaking change.

---

Finally, if you're just interested in a workaround, my usual approach is as follows:  If you're sure that `T extends U` but the compiler isn't, then you can't use `T` in a place that expects something assignable to `U`.  But you *can* use `Extract<T, U>`.  The [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) is primarily meant to filter any unions in `T` so that only those members assignable to `U` are left.  But the compiler does see `Extract<T, U>` is assignable to both `T` and `U` (possibly in [ms/TS#29437](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29437)), and if you're right that `T extends U`, then `Extract<T, U>` will eventually evaluate to just `T` as desired.  So this off-label use of `Extract` does what we want:

```
type Proof<M> = IsTrue<Extract<Refl<M>, true>> // okay
```

This is almost like a type-level [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), so similar caveats apply.  If you're wrong about `Refl<M>` being assignable to `true`, then `IsTrue<Extract<Refl<M>, true>>` would still compile, but you're no longer evaluating `IsTrue<Refl<M>>`, but something more like `IsTrue<never>` or `IsTrue<true>`.  So be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgFQE4FcIB4CCUIA9gQB2AJnFMKhAHxQC8UmAUKJFAEoQBmANugLI16fHPiKkowgPzlKUAFxROAQ25wIjZuGgAFJAHs9nfoNiJK6AKL4kSgMbB0HHsYA0MtFRoB6L1D0BrJRANFmgACQBbCLp2Ll5CCAA3CCRvXwTkpE1WJ24AJmMYgG0+AF0RAhIyEvLpCjR5RRU1AG5s8Ki8mNyCjJS09wggA)